# Fetch all Pubnub Messages for all channels

Tags: c#, pubnub

Is there a way to fetch message history for all channels in Pubnub. I see that there is for a single channel but I cant find an option to essentially dump the message history. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you can only [fetch history for a single channel](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/storage-and-history) so you will need to iterate through a list of channels. You will also need to [page through each channel](http://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/194/how-do-i-page-through-stored-messages) 100 messages at a time until you have all the messages that you require either based on number of messages or some time in the past.

I will reply with more about the future of history API if there is anything we can share publicly at this time. But there are definitely big things in store for the Storage/History features on the roadmap - stay tuned.

Comment: This is unfortunate as I have done a stress test with 10 000 channels each with a single message and it takes over 10 min to get the dump. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: Storage was not meant for large data dumps nor to used as a large scale SQL or No-SQL type database, rather, its primary purpose is to provide a way to retrieve missed messages for your end users for 1 or many channels and to sync up across multiple devices. We may extend further admin facilities on the Admin Dashboard side to allow for large data dumps and custom queries but nothing confirmed on the roadmap at this time.